# Fine-tune BERT HuggingFace with many text inputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, classification, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to fine-tune BERT / transformer model that takes tabular data as an input.

Each row has many text inputs and some numeric features.

I want to have one neural network on one side. Then a transformer on the other side. The transformer will take the text inputs. The neural network will take the numeric inputs. The outputs will be concatenated and a final dense 1 sigmoid layer will produce a prediction.

```py
def bert_model():
    num_columns = 10
    inputs = []
    numeric_inputs = layers.Input(shape = (window_size, num_columns))
    categorical_inputs = layers.Input(shape = (window_size, num_columns))
    
    inputs.append(numeric_inputs)
    inputs.append(categorical_inputs)
    
    input_ids = layers.Input(shape=(512,), name='input_token', dtype='int32')
    input_masks_ids = layers.Input(shape=(512,), name='masked_token', dtype='int32')
    unpooledoutputs = tfbert_model(input_ids, input_masks_ids)
    bert_layer = layers.Dropout(0.1)(unpooledoutputs.pooler_output)
    inputs.append(input_ids)
    inputs.append(input_masks_ids)
    # textual data
    for i in range(1, window_size):
        input_ids = layers.Input(shape=(512,), name=f'input_token_{i}', dtype='int32')
        input_masks_ids = layers.Input(shape=(512,), name=f'masked_token_{i}', dtype='int32')
        inputs.append(input_ids)
        inputs.append(input_masks_ids)
    
        unpooledoutputs = tfbert_model(input_ids, input_masks_ids)
        unpooledoutputs = layers.Dropout(0.1)(unpooledoutputs.pooler_output)
        bert_layer = layers.Concatenate()([bert_layer, \
                                                 unpooledoutputs])
    ... rest of the concatenation with other model
```

Is this the correct way to do this? I would like to use the single bert model to be fine-tuned over all of the inputs. I do want want to have to use like 50 BERT models, one for every text input, but to just have one.

Comment: Have you looked into using PyTorch datasets and dataloaders?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Yeah I am moving to PyTorch now. Seems like it will be much easier.

Comment: Before you do so, have you looked at TensorFlow / Keras to see if they have a classes to help you load data easily. I am primarily a PyTorch user.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I already moved over most of my code so not going to check. But I wasn't able to find an easy way to do it in TF.